# Need to run Socket Connection & Serial Port Connection in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, serial-port

I have a Client-Server system in C# where I am constantly receiving data from the Client through the socket. I receive a set of 8 numbers from the Client to the Server, and then this data repeats again. Once I receive one set of data, I must send them all through a Serial Port, and once completed should work on the next set of data. The send-receive to Serial Port takes a lot of time, and in the meantime, the Socket Connection has already sent lots of data. The strange thing is, after the loop completes the first time, the program hangs, and does nothing, by which I mean that the program is not triggered anymore by the Socket Connection's incoming data. Could you please tell me why this could be happening? If I need to run the Socket Connection & Serial Port on two separate threads, how could I do that?

Thank You.

Comment: My crystal ball is not working today. Can you show us relevant parts of the code that's not working? Also, on what line does it hang?

Comment: Hi Svick, I'm sorry I didn't put up the code earlier. I was no really sure where to begin. But I fixed it now. But, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a producer-consumer pattern in which one thread (the producer) receives data from the socket and puts it in a queue data structure, while another thread (the consumer) fetches data from the queue and writes sends it to the serial port.